# how i select some value equal array in Doctrine "createQueryBuilder"

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

can you help me with this code
There are several columns in the database, one of which is a role, user role value looks like this:
["ROLE_ADMIN"]
how can I get all users who have this role?

```
public function findUserWithRolle(){
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('R');
    $qb->select('R.username')
    ->where('R.roles=["ROLE_ADMIN"]');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use *"direct LIKE-approach"* you could get them like:

```
 public function findUserWithRolle(string $role = 'ROLE_ADMIN'){
   $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('R');
   $qb->select('R.username')
      ->andWhere('R.roles LIKE :role')
      ->setParameter('role', '%'.$role.'%');
   return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
 }
```

Note: There are possible some pitfalls. With "LIKE-approach". But for your case enough.